# general.el error Key sequence starts with non-prefix key

Tags: key-bindings, prefix-keys

I am having a problem with `general.el` package. I have `SPC` set as a prefix and then other keys as sub-prefix, then some other keys as actions, like how `Doom Emacs` has.

```
(nvmap :states '(normal visual) :keymaps 'override :prefix "SPC"
  "SPC"   '(find-file :which-key "Find file")
  .
  .
  .
  "m"       '(:ignore t :which-key "Org")
```

All this works.. But when I add this line,

```
"m i"     '(:ignore t :which-key "Insert")
"m i i"   '(org-insert-item :which-key "Org toggle item"))
```

It gives error saying,

> "Key sequence SPC m i i starts with non-prefix key SPC m i"

I basically want `SPC m` to be a preifx for `Org` related actions, then `i` for `Org` insert related actions.

Answer (score 1):

Run `(general-auto-unbind-keys)`.

From the readme (https://github.com/noctuid/general.el#automatic-key-unbinding):

> ### Automatic Key Unbinding
>
> To automatically prevent `Key sequence starts with a non-prefix key` errors without the need to explicitly unbind non-prefix keys, you can add `(general-auto-unbind-keys)` to your configuration file. This will advise `define-key` to unbind any bound subsequence of the `KEY`. Currently, this will only have an effect for `general.el` key definers. The advice can later be removed with `(general-auto-unbind-keys t)`.